# What order should these elements be in a Python module?

Tags: python

When present, what is the order that these elements should be declared in a Python module?

- Hash bang (`#!/usr/bin/env python`)
- Encoding (`# coding: utf-8`)
- Future imports (`from __future__ import unicode_literals, ...`)
- Docstring

If declared last, will the docstring work in a call `help(module)`?

Comment: Can't you simply test for yourself whether declaring the docstring last works with help?

Comment: oh, true, why am I searching this? haha thanks @martineau

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Hash bang. The kernel literally looks at the first two bytes of the file to see if they are equal to `#!`, so it won't work otherwise.
2. Encoding. According to the [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations) it must be "on the first or second line".
3. Docstring. According to [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring), a docstring is "a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition", so it cannot go after any import statements. You can see for yourself that `help(module)` no longer reports your docstring if you put it in a different place.
4. Future imports, because they cannot go before any of the above.

Comment: So in Python 2, if I import `unicode_literals`, is the docstring a unicode or an str?

Comment: @augustomen Good question. It's an `unicode` apparently, even if the import comes after the docstring. How that works under the hood, no idea :)